# Attempted to switch from webpack v1 syntax to webpack v3 and encountered a weird compilation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, compilation, frontend

I am working on a ReactJS login screen project and first encountered an issue with webpack (re: [Compilation Issue with a React Login Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774206/compilation-issue-with-a-react-login-screen)) to which @Andrew Li(https://stackoverflow.com/users/5647260/andrew-li) correctly prompted us switch from Webpack v1 syntax to Webpack v3 syntax.

This is the resulting config code:

https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/8134002fdfb697e34a855e0394969ffc

Upon compiling and running the code using webpack index.js run.js I get the following error about an unexpected token in a line which doesn't exist in my code. Precisely one line under my final line. 
The error:

```
 C:\Users\Jake\command line work\LearnD\Iteration 0\app\frontend>webpack 
 index.js run.js
 C:\Users\Jake\command line work\LearnD\Iteration 
 0\app\frontend\webpack.config.js:143
 });
 ^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
  at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
  at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
  at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at requireConfig 
(C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-
argv.js:97:18)
```

Any form of way pointing or correction regarding the config and getting rid of this error would be more than appreciated.

Thanks and I owe you virtual pints of beer,

J.

Comment: can you please share the entire code, maybe using gist?https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @Ido.S you are indeed a proper gentleman and Sir.
Have a look here : https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/8134002fdfb697e34a855e0394969ffc

Comment: @Ido.S  any developments ?

Comment: resolve and everything under it should be at the root level not under rules. you should add missing ```],
          },```

Comment: Thanks very much @Ido.S

Comment: that did it? ill add as answer

Answer (score 0):

resolve and everything under it should be at the root level not under rules. you should add missing `], },`  after the last rule